# How does one implement a clock that updates every second with Python and Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm working on an application that shows the current time and time until the ISS passes a location. I have it working in TKinter, but I need to deploy it and I thought flask might work.

I've found things like this

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/71/

but they don't seem to continuously update the GUI. Do you guys have any advice.

If anyone wants to see the Code implemented in TKinter, the project's github account is here https://github.com/SpaceMass/SpaceCamera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deploying online, the server is only going to send information to your browser once in response to the initial GET request. In order update the GUI with new info from the server, you would have to include an on-page script that refreshes the page once every X seconds (yuck).

Instead of grabbing that info from the server once a second, if you just want a clock on the page then you can insert it with some javascript. The following code is taken [from this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock):

```
<script>
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
```

This gives you a rolling counter of the current time. Subtract that from the time of the next ISS pass (a piece of data you can load once from the server) and you have what you want.